# Overwrite a NWJS app with an Electron one on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, node-webkit, electron, nwjs

I built an application with NWJS some time ago, but now Electron seems to be a solution which fits better my scopes.

**Problem:**

I already distributed my app and, in next releases, I would like to use Electron, but when I install it, Mac OSX cannot recognize the new release as a new version of the same application.

**Attempts:**

I tried to:

- use the same bundle identifier, bundle name, executable name;
- clone the info.plist, in order to have the same configuration for both the releases;
- clone the PkgInfo

but none of them seems to work.

On Windows I have an app identifier which does the trick: I use the same in both the applications and the installer writes in the right folder.

Is there any kind of identifier in Mac OSX too?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

It seems that in my `*.app` file there was a space... So "myApp .app" couldn't be replaced by "myApp.app".